# Apache2 stops working after running a2ensite command

Tags: apache2, lamp, localhost, virtualhost

I had my LAMP server crushed for some reason. That's why I've completely removed it and installed once again. Installation was successful and "localhost" is working fine. However every time I'm trying to add a virtual host (using a2ensite command) my apache2 server stop working. When I run a2dissite command of a corresponding virtual host, the server start working again. Please, help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Post (pastebin) the entire configuration of your problematic vitrualhost.

Comment: This is my virtual host configuration: `<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
     ServerName myhost
     ServerAlias www.myhost
     DocumentRoot /home/stas/projects/myhost
     ErrorLog /home/stas/projects/myhost/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /home/stas/projects/myhost/logs/access.log combined

 <Directory /home/stas/projects/myhost/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: I do not see anything obvious. What are the permissions on the /home/stats/projects/* directories and files ? Do the log files exist? What is in your logs?

Answer (score 1):

As of for subdomains 000-default use:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName  yourdomain.com
        ServerAlias subdomain.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /home/username/public_html/example
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/username/public_html/example>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```